# Memorials of Zhang Zhidong or Yuan Shikai

Tags: resources

Does someone know, where to get Chinese language versions of memorials (奏摺) of Zhang Zhidong or Yuan Shikai?

For Zhang Zhidong a rich source should be: 清代名人奏折书系, which I have not been able to acquire, although it might reappear on Amazon at some point.

On Yuan Shikai there ought to be 袁世凱奏摺專輯, which might be even harder to come by.

Comment: how come “奏摺” is translated as “memorials”; may i say:  **奧賣葛** 

Comment: Good question and thank you very much! Both Memorial as a Statue and as a document have to do with memory. In the case of the statue the connection is clear. In the case of the document, I believe it carries the meaning of bringing facts to the memory of the sovereign. I suspect it goes back to the times when you gave sovereigns a „memorial“ so they wouldn’t forget your plea after the audience.

Comment: “I am very grateful for the sources provided!” well, it’s easy task, imo. what will happen if i compose learning materials for literary chinese comprehension? 

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 hopefully everyone will give a bounty then!  ;)

Comment: @水巷孑蠻  memorial in english can also refer to 呈文 type documents, but this usage of the word is not common in english in regular life.  All the documents an emperor had to go through daily from the people and court members could be considered memorials for example.

Comment: @zagrycha, as usual, i always suspect my english level is . . . **low** 

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 not at all, many native english speakers won't know this definition, it is definitely not a common word in regular life  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 張之洞: the internet archive has the followings:

[張文襄公奏議、電奏](https://archive.org/search?query=%E5%BC%B5%E6%96%87%E8%A5%84%E5%85%AC%E5%A5%8F%E8%AD%B0)

the ctext.org has the same collection, but the characters recognition is . . . unbearable

the harvard university has this, the first one is mr 張’s:

[淸末名臣奏稿鈔](https://curiosity.lib.harvard.edu/chinese-rare-books/catalog/49-990085981540203941)

for 袁世凱, here’s a “privacy” version of the book 袁世凱奏摺專輯 by 國立故宮博物院:

[第一冊](https://pdf.fengshui86.com/pdf32/G325004.pdf)

[第二冊](https://pdf.fengshui86.com/pdf32/G325005.pdf)

[第三冊](https://pdf.fengshui86.com/pdf32/G325006.pdf)

[第四冊](https://pdf.fengshui86.com/pdf32/G325007.pdf)

[第五冊](https://pdf.fengshui86.com/pdf32/G325008.pdf)

[第六冊](https://pdf.fengshui86.com/pdf32/G325009.pdf)

[第七冊](https://pdf.fengshui86.com/pdf32/G325010.pdf)

[第八册](https://pdf.fengshui86.com/pdf32/G325011.pdf)

have fun